# How to write a list to a file without brackets

Tags: python, list, file-io

I have an integer list named `LineValue` of the form `[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0]`, and I need to write it to file.  To prevent a read error with my code, the form in the file needs to be

`0,1,1,2,0,0`

Instead, what I get is

`[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0]`

This causes a casting error when I try to read the file.  I could change either the read function or the write function, since both are defined in a single imported module, but I think I would prefer to change the write function, all else being equal.

write code:

```
def Write_Line(LineValue):
        with open("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/ClassValues/position","w") as f:  # Set index values for setup parameters
                f.write(str(LineValue))
```

read code:

```
def Read_Line():
        with open("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/ClassValues/position","r") as f:  # Get index values for setup parameters
                LV = f.read()
        RetValue = [int(x) for x in LV.split(",")]
        return RetValue
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.py", line 16, in <module>
    LineValue = read_Line()
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/resource.py", line 14, in Read_Line
    RetValue = [int(x) for x in LV.split(",")]
  File "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/resource.py", line 14, in <listcomp>
    RetValue = [int(x) for x in LV.split(",")]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[0'
```

Comment: This is happening because `LineValue` is a list and your code is doing a default string representation of a Python list. To get any other format you have to specify what you want. @Irhorer's way is as good as any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format it like this:

```
>>> val = [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0]
>>> print(",".join(str(i) for i in val))
0,1,1,2,0,0
>>>
```

And of course, you can call `f.write` in place of `print`.

Comment: Or `','.join(map(str,LineValue))`

Comment: Thanks!  That took care of it.  Boy, Python sure does have some... ahem... subtle distinctions.